# Using a if statement condition to see NULL user input and print: "sometext ..."

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

Python with its indents and no semi-colons and brackets is taking some time for me to  get used to ... coming from C++. This, I'm sure is an easy fix, but I can't seem to find the problem. Your help is greatly appreciated. Here is what I have. When I run this code it acts like the second 'if' statement does not exist. Even if I comment out the first 'if' statement, the print line in the second 'if' statement is never printed to screen:

```
import re


while True:
   stringName = raw_input("Convert string to hex & ascii(type stop to quit): ").strip()
   if stringName == 'stop':
      break
   if stringName is None: print "You must enter some text to proceed!"

   print "Hex value: ", stringName.encode('hex')
   print "ASCII value: ", ', '.join(str(ord(c)) for c in stringName)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The return value of `raw_input()` is always a string, and never `None`.  If you want to check for an empty string `""`, you can use

```
if not string_name:
    # whatever
```

Answer (score 1):

`raw_input` always returns a string and never `None`. Check out `raw_input` help.

> raw_input([prompt]) -> string
>
> Read a string from standard input.  The trailing newline is stripped.
>      If the user hits EOF (Unix: Ctl-D, Windows: Ctl-Z+Return), raise EOFError.
>      On Unix, GNU readline is used if enabled.  The prompt string, if given,
>      is printed without a trailing newline before reading.